# How many bee hives are there per world?

Tags: terraria

I have recently stumbled upon a jungle in my large terraria world and found a beehive inside it. Excited, I rushed in with bombs and summoned a queen bee. I tried to kill the boss but failed. After my defeat I attempted to find another bee hive in the jungle but as of now I can't find any. My question is: How many bee hives spawn per jungle and does it matter on the size of the world if it is multiple like the floating islands? I have checked the wiki and it says nothing about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hives, like many of the structures in Terraria, are generated randomly. It has been my experience that each world will always have at least one hive in each jungle biome, potentially more on a large world. Since there is more room to generate stuff, size is definitely a factor when determining how many hives there will be.

Even if your world has only one hive, you can use an [Abeemination](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Abeemination) to summon another Queen Bee to have a second chance at battling it.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually found many beehives in the underground jungle, which helps. Also, you can go to the older bee hives and just collect the items to summon the queen bee, using items such as stingers and honey. Just ask your guide to help you craft and put in a stinger!

Answer (score -1):

there may also be a problem with limited hive and honey blocks in a world so I recommend starting another one and finding another hive