# Bee Hives In Terraria

Tags: terraria-mobile

I can't find any bee hives in my world and I really need the honey for a trap. Is there really a hive in every world?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How many bee hives are there per world?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134026/how-many-bee-hives-are-there-per-world)

Comment: You can use the map viewer to see if there is one somewhere. Although that's somewhat cheating which you may not want to do. Note that the hive is in the underground jungle so that should limit your search radius.

Comment: @Frank, I agree the question is a duplicate in context, however, terrarium is different on console compared to PC and phone. Enough that the three versions use separate tags to distinguish questions. This user is asking about the mobile version, where the linked question is concerning the PC version.

Comment: @Frank not to mention the fact that the only answer to the question: "if there is a beehive in every world" is a subjective one

Comment: @Aequitas That is definitely not a subjective question. It has a hard answer: yes or no. People may answer it from a subjective perspective ("all of my worlds have had beehives"), but that doesn't make the answer itself bad. Someone could find a developer statement addressing this, or they could run a trial by generating some large number of worlds and seeing how many have beehives.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I never said that it was a subjective question. I said the only answer to the question on that link is a subjective one: "It has been my experience that each world will always have at least one hive in each jungle biome" That's not saying if it is or isn't, just that this one person in particular has always found at least one

Comment: @Aequitas Oh, I misread your comment. Carry on then. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've researched a bit and couldn't find any sources that stated there must be at least one hive.

However most people claim to have found at least one per underground jungle, with a strong chance of there being more. There is approximately 3/5/7 hives in an underground jungle (depending on world size).

Note that bee hives (and honey) were added in v1.2 so if you are running an earlier version you will not be able to find any.

Answer (score -1):

### [Bee Hives](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bee_Hive)

There are Bee Hives in Terraria worlds. More than one can be randomly generated in that world. [image: A Bee Hive in Terraria]

They are found in [Underground Jungles](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Underground_Jungle). If you cannot find it, try harder! To me, they are very common in my worlds.